# Printf nao imprime dentro do while

Tags: c, lista-encadeada, printf

o objetivo do código é imprimir os valores, de listas ligadas.
  Exemplo de como é a lista:
   L->[3]->[4]->[5]->X, 
deviria imprimir 3, 4, 5. No entanto nâo o faz.

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;


LInt insereL (LInt l, int x){
    LInt new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
    new->valor = x;
    new->prox = l;
    //printf("%d\n", new -> valor);
    return new;
}

void imprimeL (LInt l){
    while (l != NULL){
        printf("%d\n", l -> valor);
        l = l -> prox;
    }
}

int main(){
    LInt new;
    insereL(new, 5);
    insereL(new, 4);
    insereL(new, 3);
    imprimeL(new);
    //freeL(new);
    //puts("Hello World!");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: "deviria imprimir 10, 20, 30" - Como assim ? No seu código, você adicionou os valores 5, 4 e 3

Comment: Isac, esses valores era suposto ser só um exemplo, mas ja editei para perceber melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As outras respostas já indicam qual o maior problema que tem, que é não utilizar o que é retornado na função `insereL` de forma a ligar a lista, no entanto, existe ainda outro problema que é utilizar o ponteiro `LInt` sem ser inicializado:

```
LInt new;
insereL(new, 5); //utilizar new sem estar inicializado
```

O que lhe vai potencialmente dar um *segmentation fault* na parte da impressão, pois a lista não vai acabar em `NULL` como seria suposto.

Para corrigir esses dois problemas precisa de alterar o `main`:

```
int main(){
    //iniciar com NULL que serve para o fim da lista, e que joga com a parte da impressão 
    //quando faz while (l != NULL){
    LInt new = NULL; 

    new = insereL(new, 5); //guarda resultado de novo em new, que é a nova cabeça da lista
    new = insereL(new, 4); //guarda neste tambem
    new = insereL(new, 3); //e neste
    imprimeL(new);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

[Veja no Ideone como já funciona com essas altearções](https://ideone.com/XR7aT0)

Haveriam certamente outras recomendações a fazer, mas vou me resumir apenas a uma, mudar o nome da variável `new`, pelos seguintes motivos:

- Todas as outras variáveis que tem estão escritas em português, logo esta deve estar também, dando assim mais coerência ao código. Um nome razoável seria `novo`, ou `novo_no`.
- `new` é uma palavra reservada em c++, isso é visível pela cor especial que vê aqui dada à palavra. Isto significa que o seu código não só não é portável para C++ como dificulta a leitura a quem perceba c++.

Answer (score 1):

O seu código não modifica a variável  Lint que recebe como primeiro parâmetro, você cria um elemento novo e retorna mas isso não é armazenado e por isso quando imprime a lista está vazia.

Answer (score 1):

A função **insereL** não conecta os objetos criados, ou seja, quando na hora de imprimir você "anda" entre os objetos

```
l = l -> prox;
```

não está apontando para os objetos instanciados na função **insereL**.